# why we need to use double quotes to call the index of the global variable _G?

Tags: indexing, lua, global, lua-table

I realized that when I try to work with the `_G` variable to analyze global variables, I need to use double quotes in the index to find the variable, for example:

It does not work:

```lua
varname = 5

print(_G[varname]) -- nil
```

but this works:

```lua
varname = 5

print(_G["varname"]) -- 5
```

why are these quotes necessary? does it store variables in the table `_G` as `"varname" = varname` ?

Comment: `_G[i]` is needed for getting `_G[5]` when `i=5`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're getting at. I know how to declare and collect values with the `_G` variable, what I don’t understand is why I need to use the double quotes in the index when collecting a value from a variable inside it, because in the first example it didn't work, but in the second it did

Comment: For tables: `t={varname=5, 1}`. when you call `t[1]` it will return 1 and `t["varname"]` or `t.varname` will return 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening when you run the code you provided, without quotes:

```lua
varname = 5
print(_G[varname]) --> << varname >> resolves to << 5 >>
```

becomes:

```lua
varname = 5
print(_G[5]) --> _G[5] resolves to << nil >> because there is no such key << 5 >> in the global table
```

becomes:

```lua
varname = 5
print(nil) --> Prints << nil >> because it is, nil.
```

As you can see, you're accessing `_G[varname]`. `varname` is an `identifier` (a variable name) which is evaluated as the *integral value 5*.

When you use quotes, `"varname"` is a `string`, no longer an identifier, it is evaluated as the *string value "varname"*.

`_G["varname"]` is equivalent of writing `_G.varname`, which is defined in this code:

```lua
varname = 5
print(_G["varname"])
```

is equivalent to:

```lua
varname = 5
print(_G.varname)
```

which, in this context, is equivalent to:

```lua
varname = 5
print(varname)
```

which becomes:

```lua
varname = 5
print(5)
```

The rule here is that `table['identifier_string']` can be written `table.identifier_string`, because `identifier_string` is a valid variable-name. If you want to index a table with a string having a space for instance: `table['hello world']`, you then can *not* use the equivalent notation; `table.hello world` is invalid.